# Celery doesn't found postgres container

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, celery

I use django and celery in my project with docker. In docker, i have three containers: app, celery, postgres

In the celery task, when i tried to get a model:

```
@app.task
def test():
    Model.objects.get(pk=1)
```

, i had this error:

```
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

That error comes from the **celery container**. If i remove this lodel call, everything works well.

The postgres container is at port 5432, it works well with app container.

I thought that maybe because when the celery task executes, the task itself is not part django project, so it doesn't have the right configuration.

I tried django-celery, but had the same error.

Comment: You will have to configure the right hostname for postgresql in celery. It should be the postgresql container name.

Comment: @KlausD. how could i do that ? sorry, i'm pretty new with celery and django

Comment: That hardly depends on how you use celery and what tasks you are running. If the task are Django based, then you should check the Django config.